# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Tags: c#

The same code is working in Windows 10 but not in Windows Server 2012 R2.

```
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();

        start.FileName = "java";
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.CreateNoWindow = true;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start.RedirectStandardError = true;

        start.Arguments = @"-jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar tojson input.avro";

        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        //in above line is where the error appears.
```

I checked the path and is ok. I run it from command line and is working. Not sure what else to check.

Comment: have you tried `UseShellExecute = true`?

Comment: have you tried "java.exe" or a full path?

Comment: @DanielA.White, I think I cannot use it. System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.'

Comment: @Max I tried java.exe full path, got the same result, I think that won't work either since the .jar and .avro file are not in the same location as java. Just to clarify in console is working.

Comment: That's strange. I just compiled and run your code at Windows 2012 R2 (6.3.9600). It worked just fine. Paths to jar/avro files are not checked by Windows -- they are just strings passed to Java -- java will throw error, but Java has to start to check that.

Comment: may be try to add `ErrorDialog = true` just for debugging purposes, might give more info. Also, what about `FileName="cmd.exe"` and `Arguments="/C java -jar ..."`. It's not elegant, but worth to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution was to add a new profile as x64 and run the debugger with it.